# Prevent appending duplicate lines to .bash_profile

Tags: node.js, macos, unix

I am creating a program that will append a line to .bash_profile on behalf of the user. However, my program may be re-inited on the machine many times by the same user. Instead of adding an arbitrary number of duplicate lines in the .bash_profile file, how can I ensure this line is only appended once to the file?
The most straightforward way would be to read the .bash_profile file in and look at each line and only add a new line if the line doesn't exist yet, is there a better way?

Comment: What is the line that is appended? It might make a difference in that regard.

Comment: sure, the line is: export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g):$NODE_PATH

Comment: if there are duplicates of this line, it's not a big deal, but I'd rather avoid dupes

Comment: Since it's an export variable you could likely just check that without needing to read the lines of .bash_profie (eg. echo $NODE_PATH). if you did want to check the file then awk, sed, or grep would also probably work fine. If there was already a value set are you wanting to remove it and replace it, or just ignore appending the value?

Answer (score 2):

> The most straightforward way would be to read the .bash_profile file
>   in and look at each line and only add a new line if the line doesn't
>   exist yet, is there a better way?

There is no better way. Checking whether the variable `NODE_PATH` is already set as desired can't work until the user has logged in again, thus it wouldn't prevent appending duplicate lines before that.

```
line='export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g):$NODE_PATH'
grep "$line" .bash_profile||echo $line >>.bash_profile
```